# Rails postgres default database user when using --database=postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I feel like I should know this, but I don't!

When creating a new rails app with `--database=postgresql` the database.yml looks like:

```
...
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: big_bustas_development
...
```

Now I can do all manner of `rails db:create` ...migrate...ect without explitly configuring a database user and password. What postgres credentials is rails using the accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PostgreSQL by default use your OS username. The default authentication mode for PostgreSQL is set to **ident**. Read [this article](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/what-is-the-default-password-for-postgresql/) and/or [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT) for more information.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!